# What do negative & positive accelerations stand for exactly ? ( iOS )

Tags: ios, iphone, accelerometer

*Please excuse me in advance if I should be asking this in a Physics forum, but given that I'm talking about the iPhone's acceleration, coming from the accelerometer, I decided to post it here.*

Whenever I push the iPhone (device lying on the table - screen facing upwards) forward (towards the top of the device), the accelerometer seems to be recording negative acceleration for the most part, with a few positive acceleration values, on that same Y-axis, appearing here and there from time to time.

This is a sample of the **acceleration values on the Y-axis,** during such a **forward movement** across the Y-axis :

```
-0.02
-0.03
-0.04
-0.03
-0.04
-0.04
-0.07
-0.02
-0.02
-0.02
-0.02
 0.00 // what's happening here ?
 0.02 // what's happening here ?
 0.02 // what's happening here ?
-0.00
-0.02
-0.03
-0.03
 0.02 // what's happening here ?
 0.04 // what's happening here ?
 0.01 // what's happening here ?
-0.00
-0.04
-0.03
-0.02
-0.03
-0.05
```

What do the negative acceleration values stand for and what do the positive ones stand for in the above example ?

If I understand correctly, negative acceleration values mean the device is accelerating forward at that point.

Now, positive acceleration values would mean the device is moving backwards, while 0.00 acceleration would mean the device is either standing still* or moving at a constant speed.

So why do I get those positive acceleration values during that forward movement of the device?

Am I missing something ?

The only reason I'm asking, obviously, is because I want to create a method in order to know whether the device is moving forward or backwards on the Y-axis.

*I also noticed a 0.01 value comes and goes even when the device is completely immobile, but I'm guessing this is just noise, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So why do I get those positive acceleration values during that forward movement of the device?

Ehm, you seem to be understanding that an acceleration of 0 means no acceleration, i. e. being still or moving at a constant speed. Now if you move the phone at a seemingly constant speed in one direction, it might not be perfectly constant - both small positive and negative accelerations may occur.

> *I also noticed a 0.01 value comes and goes even when the device is completely immobile, but I'm guessing this is just "noise" right?

Right. The accelerometer sensor is not perfect. It reacts to many other factors than just pure acceleration. I'm not aware of the exact internals of how the iPhone's accelerometer works, but if I guess right, it's a piezoelectric one, so it can be sensitive to other kind of physical (mechanical and electromagnetic) effects.

Comment: So what would the `small positive accelerations` stand for in the case of the forward movement I presented? The negative ones occur because of the forward movement, but what about the positive ones?

Comment: @LukaP. No. They are not the result of the *movement*. They're the result of the *acceleration*. If you fail to move the phone at a perfectly constant speed, there will be acceleration and deceleration in its movement - the latter is indicated by the positive acceleration value.

Comment: If deceleration is indicated by the positive acceleration value, what is decreasing negative acceleration indicating ?

Comment: @LukaP. it indicates decreasing forward acceleration.

Comment: But you just said that positive acceleration is the one indicating deceleration. I'm confused. :) Ok to put more clearly : In the above example in my OP, what is decreasing negative acceleration indicating and what is positive acceleration indicating ?

Comment: @LukaP there's nothing controversary in the two, in fact they're straight equivalent. Forward acceleration seems to be negative. Backwards acceleration (that can be *forwards deceleration*) has a positive value. (Please read the relevant unit of a high school physics book.)

Comment: Oh now I see what you were trying to say. So if I'm walking forward and then I start to slow down _while_ still walking forward then I'm actually accelerating at the opposite direction at the same time even though I'm not moving in that opposite direction. Wow. Can't remember which high school book said that but I'll have a look anyway. Thanks! :)

Comment: You can prove what @H2CO3 is say very easily, hold your device upside down, what was the signs of your values will reverse, but the velocities won't. The numbers are the amount of force being applied moving the device away or from you. Not the speed and not the direction. Acceleration is rate of change of velocity.

Comment: The only problem with that is that I can't use the accelerometer to know which direction the device is moving in on the y-axis, given that negative & positive accelerations can be recorded in both directions. So I can't write something like : `if(acceleration.y < 0){movesFWD = YES;} else {movesBWD = YES;}`. Oh well.. :)

Comment: @LukaP. true story. It's the reason why the accelerometer is called an accelerometer and not a speedometer :)

Comment: Not really. Measuring speed wouldn't give me direction either. :) I have more chances achieving that by messing with the acceleration, even though it's going to be hard and maybe even impossible. Also, an accelerometer _is_ a speedometer given that it can measure acceleration and you can get speed from acceleration & time. It's just going to return a speed as inaccurate as the acceleration but in accordance with it nonetheless.

Comment: @LukaP. If you had a **signed** speed, you could get direction from its sign (e. g. positive: forward, negative: backwards).